# Replace preg_replace with preg_replace_callback

Tags: php, preg-replace, preg-replace-callback

I'm using a framework with the following preg_replace in one of the files, it's giving me an error:

> [Deprecated] preg_replace(): The /e modifier is deprecated, use
>   preg_replace_callback instead

Can someone advise how I'd modify this to use preg_replace_callback, please?

```
$search = array(
                               '/\s+>\s+/', // Matches any element that is a child of parent.
                               '/\s+\+\s+/', // Matches any element that is an adjacent sibling.
                               '/\s+/', // Matches any element that is a descendant of an parent element element.
                               '/(\w)\[(\w+)\]/', // Matches element with attribute
                               '/(\w)\[(\w+)\=[\'"]?(\w+)[\'"]?\]/', // Matches element with EXACT attribute
                               '/(\w+)?\#([\w\-]+)/e', // Matches id attributes
                               '/(\w+|[\*\]])?((\.[\w\-]+)+)/e', // Matches class attributes
            );
            $replace = array(
                               '/',
                               '/following-sibling::*[1]/self::',
                               '//',
                               '\\1[@\\2]',
                               '\\1[@\\2="\\3"]',
                               "(strlen('\\1') ? '\\1' : '*').'[@id=\"\\2\"]'",
                               "(strlen('\\1') ? '\\1' : '*').'[contains(concat(\" \",@class,\" \"),concat(\" \",\"'.implode('\",\" \"))][contains(concat(\" \",@class,\" \"),concat(\" \",\"',explode('.',substr('\\2',1))).'\",\" \"))]'",
            );
            $xpathcache[$xpathkey] = '//'.preg_replace($search,$replace,$css_selector);
```

Thank you

Comment: I am also experiencing this, did you find a solution?

Comment: @nickspiel IIRC I did, yes. I'm in the office at the moment and it was on a home project. I've set myself a reminder to chase this up and post back tonight for you with (hopefully) the solution.